# bad credentials error while authenticating

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to login to my api on a spring boot.
Here is my controller:

```
package com.example.angularspringcrud.controller;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.angularspringcrud.model.ERole;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.model.Role;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.model.User;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.payload.request.LoginRequest;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.payload.request.SignupRequest;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.payload.response.JwtResponse;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.payload.response.MessageResponse;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.security.services.UserDetailsImpl;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    
    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        System.out.println(encoder.encode(loginRequest.getPassword()));
        
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(),loginRequest.getPassword()));

System.out.println(authentication.getName());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();      
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, 
                 userDetails.getLastname(), userDetails.getId(), 
                 userDetails.getUsername(), 
                 userDetails.getName(), 
                 
                 userDetails.getPatronimic(),null, roles)); 
        }
    
    
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

    

        // Create new user's account
        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(), 
                 signUpRequest.getName(),
                 signUpRequest.getLastname(), signUpRequest.getPatronimic(),
                 new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()),
                 
                 null);
        
        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_NOTCONFIRMED)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                case "admin":
                    Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(adminRole);

                    break;
                case "mod":
                    Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_TEACHER)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(modRole);

                    break;
                    
                case "std":
                    Role stdRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_STUDENT)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(stdRole);

                    break;
                default:
                    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_NOTCONFIRMED)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
    }
}
```

Registration is working ok. But then I try to login I get the bad credentials error. Here is my security config:

```
package com.example.angularspringcrud.security;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;


import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.example.angularspringcrud.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    
    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

UserDetailsImpl looks as follows:

```
package com.example.angularspringcrud.security.services;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import com.example.angularspringcrud.model.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
     private String patronimic;
     
        
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    
    public UserDetailsImpl(Long id, String username, String name, String lastname, String patronimic, String password,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.patronimic = patronimic;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }



    public static UserDetailsImpl build(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new UserDetailsImpl(
                user.getId(), 
                user.getUsername(), 
                user.getPassword(), 
                user.getName(),
                user.getLastname(),
                user.getPatronimic(),
                authorities);
    }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return authorities;
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //password=new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password);
        
        return password;

    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return username;

    }
    
    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name;

    }
    
    public String getLastname() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return lastname;

    }
    public String getPatronimic() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return patronimic;

    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, user.id);
    }
    
    

}
```

What am I missing? I tryed to encode password using BCrypt during the registration process but this didn't help.

**Full stack trace**

```
2022-01-28 09:43:40.901 DEBUG 22184 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.angularspringcrud.controller.AuthController#authenticateUser(LoginRequest)
2022-01-28 09:43:40.902 DEBUG 22184 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/api/auth/signin", parameters={}
2022-01-28 09:43:40.902 DEBUG 22184 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.angularspringcrud.controller.AuthController#authenticateUser(LoginRequest)
2022-01-28 09:43:40.903 DEBUG 22184 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [com.example.angularspringcrud.payload.request.LoginRequest@613ae709]
$2a$10$a9JsvihY3.3g.xj12gewF.1xOZTrZC/QnLp7k6S7Zr7Hm7pHvBenG
2022-01-28 09:43:40.972 DEBUG 22184 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.id as id1_2_, user0_.lastname as lastname2_2_, user0_.name as name3_2_, user0_.password as password4_2_, user0_.patronimic as patronim5_2_, user0_.username as username6_2_ from users user0_ where user0_.username=?
2022-01-28 09:43:40.973 DEBUG 22184 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select roles0_.user_id as user_id1_1_0_, roles0_.role_id as role_id2_1_0_, role1_.id as id1_0_1_, role1_.name as name2_0_1_ from user_roles roles0_ inner join roles role1_ on roles0_.role_id=role1_.id where roles0_.user_id=?
2022-01-28 09:43:40.975  WARN 22184 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
2022-01-28 09:43:40.975 DEBUG 22184 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

**Authentication method**

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        System.out.println(encoder.encode(loginRequest.getPassword()));
        
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(),encoder.encode(loginRequest.getPassword())));

System.out.println(authentication.getCredentials());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();      
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, 
                 userDetails.getLastname(), userDetails.getId(), 
                 userDetails.getUsername(), 
                 userDetails.getName(), 
                 
                 userDetails.getPatronimic(),null, roles)); 
        }
```

**Registration**

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

    

        // Create new user's account
        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(), 
                 signUpRequest.getName(),
                 signUpRequest.getLastname(), signUpRequest.getPatronimic(),
                // signUpRequest.getPassword(),
                 encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()),
                 
                 null);
        
        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_NOTCONFIRMED)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                case "admin":
                    Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(adminRole);

                    break;
                case "mod":
                    Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_TEACHER)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(modRole);

                    break;
                    
                case "std":
                    Role stdRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_STUDENT)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(stdRole);

                    break;
                default:
                    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_NOTCONFIRMED)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
    }
```

**My Auth entery point**

```
package com.example.angularspringcrud.security.jwt;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

      private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
         logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
          }
    

}
```

**Log after submiting a form**
parse

```
null
null
2022-01-28 18:27:16.203 DEBUG 5324 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/api/auth/signin", parameters={}
2022-01-28 18:27:16.204 DEBUG 5324 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.angularspringcrud.controller.AuthController#authenticateUser(LoginRequest)
2022-01-28 18:27:16.205 DEBUG 5324 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [com.example.angularspringcrud.payload.request.LoginRequest@7a9ad323]
$2a$10$mP0xyGc24.ej46iAO0cdSePNTV2dmhX1lTcjBuDZIA213F.XsrMCu
2022-01-28 18:27:16.344  WARN 5324 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
2022-01-28 18:27:16.344 DEBUG 5324 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
2022-01-28 18:27:16.345 ERROR 5324 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.a.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt     : Unauthorized error: Bad credentials
```

**UserDetailsService**

```
package com.example.angularspringcrud.security.services;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.angularspringcrud.model.User;
import com.example.angularspringcrud.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
      UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Override
      @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));

    
    System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using the built in JWT filter that comes with spring security?

Comment: @Toerktumlare Well it is my very first implementation of login functionality. I followed this tutorial if honestly. https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-security-postgresql-jwt-authentication/#Setup_new_Spring_Boot_project

Comment: that tutorial is full of faulty information, if you are just getting started, why didn't you just read the official spring security documentation before asking on stack overflow.

Comment: also why are you `new BCryptPasswordEncoder()` and not using the autowired one?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I tryed. But result is the same as a new BCrypt.

Comment: then please update your code with what you have tried, im not going to sit here and try to solve your problem with you just answering "i have tried that" that is just rude and wastes peoples time.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I am sorry for that. Here is what I did try so far in a controller. Will update it now.

Comment: post your FULL logs, why is there 2 SQL calls in your logs, where are those SQL calls being made from.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Here is my log after submiting a form. With those 2 sql queries I am getting user name from a service and User roles.

Comment: where is `UserDetailsServiceImpl` and why do you have one? when you are handling the authentication by yourself in the filter. You either use springs built in mechanisms or you write your own custom filters. You have mashed together both.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Already posted it. I just need to get other information from user Firstname, Lastname for example.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have a same issue in authenticate part. Here is the my code  `Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));` How can I fix it?

Comment: its against the rules to post new questions in comments.